# how to get data if value exist else return default

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this two data from my database which is the only difference is their status

```
id   |   userId    |  status   |  dateCreated
1    |     1       |  pending  |   2019-02-09 22:11:11
2    |     1       |  complete |   2019-02-10 10:40:20
```

what i wanted to do is to get the data with status `complete` if status  `complete` exist based on the id else get the status `pending` if `complete` status not exist

i tried using SELECT CASE statement but what happens is it returns both pending and complete status

the reason why i didn't just update the 1st data is for reports purposes.

is there a way to get this?
here is my sample query.

```
SELECT userId,
CASE
    WHEN status = 'completed' THEN "completed"
    ELSE "pending"
END AS status
FROM tbltransaction where userId = '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
SELECT userId,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbltransaction WHERE userId = '1' AND status = 'completed') THEN 'completed'
    ELSE 'pending'
  END AS status
FROM tbltransaction where userId = '1'
```

Comment: thanks this works.. didn't thought to use when exists on case statement..

Comment: It is common practice to use exists after when since it returns a true/false (boolean) value.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation returns one row per user:

```
SELECT userId,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(status = 'completed') > 0 THEN 'completed'
             ELSE 'pending'
        END) AS status
FROM tbltransaction 
WHERE userId = 1
GROUP BY userId;
```

Alternatively, if you only care about one user, you could use:

```
SELECT 1 as userId,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM tbltransaction t
                          WHERE t.userId = 1 AND
                                t.status = 'completed'
                         )
             THEN 'completed'
             ELSE 'pending'
         END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but from what you describe, it looks like you want the latest status for a given userId. I'm also assuming `id` is an Auto Increment column. If this is the case, then maybe you can try this

```
SELECT userId, status FROM tbltransaction tbl1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT userId, max(id) as max_id
  FROM tbltransaction 
  GROUP BY userId
) tbl2
ON tbl1.userId = tbl2.userId
AND tbl1.id = tbl2.max_id;
```

This would return the latest status for all users under the above assumptions.

Hope this helps! Cheers!